# Vegetarianism versus Bal Tashchis?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

According to those that hold vegetarianism is the higher & more exalted path (Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch, Rav Kook, The Nazir of Yerushalayim, Rav Shlomo Goren) what should be done if a piece of meat is on its way to a trash-bin? Would it not be more dignified for the animals sake to eat it so that he doesn’t go completely wasted? When consumed he can become part of you, energize you, & even partake & become exalted through the good deeds you perform? Or maybe it would be better for the meat to just be thrown away? I personally just came to the conclusion that I no longer find it necessary (nor particularly nice!) to eat meat anymore because of all the amazing Kosher food that exists today but my family are very carnivorous & I usually end up throwing out lots of leftovers. Although I understand that this is an “ask a Rav” type question still any input would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank You & Be Blessed!

Comment: **I don’t have a Rav to ask so any input would be greatly appreciated.** Please find yourself one. It is very important as we don't know you personally. And while the question is good, that line alone gives me a temptation to close as "Request for Psak"

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That's "bal tashchit" בל; not בעל. Embarrassingly common mistake...

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud reads (BT, [Shab. 140b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.140b.9?with=all&lang=bi)):

> ואמר רב פפא האי מאן דאפשר למישתי שיכרא ושתי חמרא עובר משום בל תשחית ולאו מילתא היא בל תשחית דגופא עדיף

Trans. (Sefaria):

> **And Rav Pappa said: One who is able to drink beer and nevertheless drinks wine violates the prohibition against wanton destruction**. The Gemara comments: **And this is not a correct matter, as the prohibition against destruction of one’s body takes precedence**. It is preferable for one to care for his body by eating higher quality food than to conserve his money.

Based on this amoraic extension of the prohibition of '*bal tashchit*' (waste), in which causing bodily deterioration is a bigger sin, I don't think in the given situation the meat would be discarded and not eaten.